# Experiencing IP conflicts restoring Cassandra DB from snapshots in GKE environment

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

While restoring 750TB Cassandra database using disk snapshots in GKE (google cloud K8s) environment from one namespace to another namespace we are experiencing issues with IP conflicts, to avoid the conflict we had a different cluster name but still seeing below errors sometime when bringing up the target node. Out of 3 restores, strangley one time it is working but other 2 times it is not.

````
INFO  20:09:50 JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.12.1.2). If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.12.1.2). If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithStrictSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:294)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:177)
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:87)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1573)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:1023)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:717)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:651)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:388)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:742)
ERROR 20:09:50 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.12.1.2). If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithStrictSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:294) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:177) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:87) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1573) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:1023) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:717) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:651) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:388) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:742) [apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]```
````

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted doesn't seem to be related to restoring snapshots.

It indicates that you're trying to bootstrap a new node into the cluster but one of the replicas it needs as the data source for streaming is unavailable.

Note that you can only bootstrap one node at a time, not multiple nodes in parallel. Once one node has fully completed bootstrapping then you can bootstrap another node. Cheers!